# Android Base64 returns string much bigger than the image

Tags: android, image, bitmap

I need to send an image to a server ,
I have an Image of 3.30 MB size , I convert it to byte array using :

```
 ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
    byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
```

then to base64 using :

```
Base64.encodeToString(byteArray , Base64.DEFAULT)
```

EDIT: If I check the length of the byte array (bytearray) it is 20 MB!
but on the PC or the phone the size show 3.30 MB

The length of the returned string is 28 MB, any explanation and solution?

Comment: "I have an Image of 3.30 MB size" -- what **exactly** do you mean by that? Are you measuring the memory consumed by `bmp? Are you referring to the size of some file that you use to create `bmp`? Do you mean something else?

Comment: It is the size shown when i click the image properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are compressing the bitmap with quality of 100 and PNG. Use JPEG and 60 or 75 quality instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("path to file");
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos); //bm is the bitmap 
object   
byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You compress the bitmap with quality 100 means no much compresion and the resultant image is bigger in this first code:

```
 ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
    byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
```

byteArray have here 20MB

Is normal that Base64 encode be bigger than byte array

Base64 was created to send/store binary data where you only cand send text
 and utilizes 64 characters of the 256 in the byte or the same for each bytes uses only 6 bits of the 8
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64

```
Base64.encodeToString(byteArray , Base64.DEFAULT)
```